# Does ASP .NET Session reset after login?

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-session

**EDIT**

This problem seems to have strangely disappeared. There must've been something funky with my environment. I'm voting to close this question.

---

When a user logs in, I inflate the session with a bunch of data from the Login page code-behind. Then I redirect the user to a different page in the application. I also have some session recovery logic which re-inflates the session based on the auth ticket when the user's session expires.

What seems to be happening is that I inflate the user's session with a bunch of data from the login page, then redirect them, and the request for the page to which I redirect them doesn't seem to have the session, so the application has to re-inflate it. I don't understand this - I've looked at the cookie and the session ID is not changing, and I am not resetting the session data anywhere in the code. Is this an ASP .NET 'feauture'? I'm using ASP .NET 4.0.

**Edit:**

To clarify: The session is inflated during the login request (on the click even of the login button). During the next request, it doesn't appear the session is populated any longer, so I end up having to re-inflate the session. Any requests that user makes after that, the session seems to "stick" and I have the properly inflated session for subsequent requests.

Comment: When in the page cycle do you populate the session on login - in the button click?  Are all your pages under the same domain?  Do you have session enabled?

Comment: I believe I've addressed your question in the edition I just made to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question `SessionState` data is independent of login/logout.

There are several reasons why data might "disappear" from `SessionState`.

- If you are using `InProc` `SessionState` on a web farm, the user may have a subsequent request be served by a different machine in the farm.
- `SessionState` can clear if it gets too full (like a cache).
- If you are using a custom `SessionStateStoreProvider`, it may not be saving/retrieving the `SessionState` properly.

Comment: All good thoughts. However, I'm not using a web farm (this is on my local box), The session is not full, and I'm not using a custom SessionStateStoreProvider - I'm using `InProc`. The session is inflated during the login request, then the next request, I end up having to re-inflate the session, and any requests after that, it seems to "stick" and I have the properly inflated session from that point forward.