# Retrieving Session after login in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I want to make a shopping cart using a Session. What I do is use a base Controller where I assign a new cart in my Session["cart"].

As expected, when I go through different pages and go back to my "cart" page, the cart still exists with the products in it.

But as soon as I log in, my Session is null. How do I keep my session alive after login, or assign my previous session data to the new one?

My BaseController class:

```
 protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        if(Session["cart"] == null)
        {
            Session["cart"] = new Order();
        }
    }
```

My Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
                {
                    var id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                    var ticket = (id.Ticket);
                    ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(id.Ticket.Name);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticket.UserData))
                    {
                        string userData = ticket.UserData;
                        string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                        HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I feel like there is something to do in this global.asax file, but I don't quite know what. Thanks for your help!

Comment: try initializing Session["cart"] in Session_Start

Comment: Check this please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293159/does-asp-net-session-reset-after-login
You are doing something wrong, because session should not be reset after login.

Comment: Check the `web.config`: `<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="10" />`